# A unitary space, interpreted as a Euclidean space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthonormal

Let $(V, \gamma)$ be a $n$-dimensional unitary space. Let $V_{\mathbb{R}}$ be the vector space $V$, interpreted as a $2n$-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space.

I first want to show that $(V_{\mathbb{R}}, \gamma_{\mathbb{R}})$ is a Euclidean space with the transformation:

$$\gamma_\mathbb{R}: V_\mathbb{R} \times V_\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \gamma_\mathbb{R}(x, y) = Re(\gamma(x, y))$$

Also, I want to show that $||v||_\gamma = ||v||_{\gamma_\mathbb{R}}$, and that, in case $(v_1, ..., v_n)$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$, $(v_1, i v_1, ..., v_n, i v_n)$ is an orthonormal basis of $V_\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: How far have you come in that? What difficulties did you encounter?

Comment: Well I already fail to see the first thing I want to show. The bilinearity of $\gamma_{\mathbb{R}}$ apparently follows from the sesquilinearity of $\gamma$, but I can't see why $\gamma_{\mathbb{R}}$ is positive definite which is required for it to be an Euclidian space. The elements of $V_\mathbb{R}$ are vectors of the shape $(v_1, v_2, ..., v_{2n-1}, v_{2n})$, so this could be used to figure out the second statement, but I'm not entirely sure how. This would probably help with the last statement because the vectors of the new ONB are already scaled right, but why are they orthogonal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The bilinearity of $\gamma_{\mathbb{R}}$ apparently follows from the sesquilinearity of $\gamma$,

Correct. Since $\gamma$ is sesquilinear, it is $\mathbb{R}$-bilinear, and composition with an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map preserves $\mathbb{R}$-bilinearity. $\operatorname{Re}\colon \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{R}$-linear.

> but I can't see why $\gamma_{\mathbb{R}}$ is positive definite

Because $\gamma$ is. For $x\neq 0$, we have $0 < \gamma(x,x) = \operatorname{Re} \gamma(x,x) = \gamma_{\mathbb{R}}(x,x)$.

That incidentally also immediately shows $\lVert v\rVert_\gamma = \sqrt{\gamma(v,v)} = \sqrt{\gamma_{\mathbb{R}}(v,v)} = \lVert v\rVert_{\gamma_{\mathbb{R}}}$ for all $v\in V$.

> The elements of $V_{\mathbb{R}}$ are

precisely the elements of $V$. We change nothing with the elements, all we do is "forget" that we can multiply with complex scalars, and restrict our attention to multiplication with real scalars. The underlying set of $V_{\mathbb{R}}$ and the additive group structure are the same as those of $V$. Only scalra multiplication is restricted from $\mathbb{C}\times V \to V$ to $\mathbb{R}\times V \to V$.

If $(v_1,\dotsc, v_n)$ is an ONB of $V$, then we have

$$\lVert v_k\rVert_{\gamma_{\mathbb{R}}} = \lVert v_k\rVert_\gamma = \lVert iv_k\rVert_\gamma = \lVert iv_k\rVert_{\gamma_{\mathbb{R}}} = 1$$

for $1 \leqslant k \leqslant n$, so the norms are right. Now we need to see that the vectors are mutually orthogonal. For $k\neq j$, we have

$$\gamma_{\mathbb{R}}(i^m v_k, i^\ell v_j) = \operatorname{Re} \gamma(i^m v_k, i^\ell v_j) = \operatorname{Re} \bigl(i^{m-\ell}\gamma(v_k,v_j)\bigr) = \operatorname{Re} \bigl(i^{m-\ell}\cdot 0) = 0,$$

so the orthogonality for $v_k, v_j$, $v_k, iv_j$, $iv_k, v_j$ and $iv_k, iv_j$. What is missing is the orthogonality of $v_k, iv_k$. But

$$\gamma_{\mathbb{R}}(v_k,iv_k) = \operatorname{Re} \gamma(v_k,iv_k) = \operatorname{Re} (-i\gamma(v_k,v_k)) = \operatorname{Re} (-i) = 0.$$

Comment: Ok, so my main problem apparently was that I had a misconception of $V_\mathbb{R}$ and it's elements. With having in mind that the only difference between $V$ and $V_\mathbb{R}$ is that one has a complex scalar multiplikation and the other one just a real multiplication, the rest is quite understandable now. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it helped.